# What is the meaning of 「でしたか」 in the sentence「あなたの職場はテプラでしたかネームランドでしたか？」?

Tags: grammar, particles

I understand the question is asking about whether the workplace uses テプラ or ネームランド cameras, but what exactly does the 「でしたか」 mean in this circumstance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up Tepra (テプラ) on google images and its a handheld machine makes something like nameplates on the go. Please correct if I am wrong!

Anyway, this usage of でしたか is as straight-forward as it gets: past tense of です + question particle か. Listing consecutive items using か gives a " [this] or [that]" list, like in your example.

> あなたの職場はテプラでしたかネームランドでしたか

More context is definitely needed for this to fully make sense, so I had to infer as to not make a nonsensical statement.

> (Did your workplace use) Tepra or Nameland (nameplate machines)?

Comment: In English we might say "Were you a Tepra shop or a name-brand shop?"

Comment: While your interpretation sounds correct I have never seen this usage before. I wonder if it's very formal or no longer in popular use. Typically I would expect something like "XかY”. It makes more sense to me if this is really two sentences, where a period is after the first でしたか。I have also seen それとも used in a similar structure after the first option.

Comment: That's not namebrand, but [Nameland](http://casio.jp/d-stationery/nameland/), another [label printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_printer).